# How do I substite a value from a dataframe in R with a value from another section of the data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, substitution

I have imported a data set into R & have discovered one outlier. I want to do specific substitution on this initially imported data. Specifically, my data looks like the following:

```
Adhesive TestCond Lab Speci.no Sample.id Wood.fail Shear.str
1        W      BDF   A   ABW-01         1       100 707.99296
2        W      BDF   A   ABW-02         2       100 557.61752
3        W      BDF   A   ABW-03         3       100 759.13431
4        W      BDF   A   ABW-04         4       100  84.70696
5        W      BDF   A   ABW-05         5       100 519.56020
6        W      BDF   A   ABW-06         6       100 502.13246
```

It has approximately 3,000 rows. This data was imported using the following command:

```
FPInnovation <- read.csv()
```

The Wood.fail value that is problematic is the following value

```
Adhesive TestCond Lab Speci.no Sample.id Wood.fail Shear.str
6        W      BDF   D   DBW-07         7       0 23.68061
```

The value of 0 within the Wood.fail column has been discovered to be an error. Other values of 0 might not be. Thus, I only want to do the substitution in the row above. How do I substitute the specific Wood.fail value of 0 (that is noted above) with the value that is held in the following row (substitute 0 above with 90 below):

```
Adhesive TestCond Lab Speci.no Sample.id Wood.fail Shear.str
31        W      BDF   D   DBW-31         31     90 237.3734
```

Comment: If you know the row number (`row.id`): `FPInnovation$Wood.fail[row.id] <- 90`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! That is an easy fix. Now, I am thinking ahead about cases where my data set is much larger. What if I don't know the row number and wanted to substitute the values for the Wood.fail where Speci.no=="DBW-07"? I can think of how to do this in SQL. Is there a similar way to do this in R?

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Missed this during my own digging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just indexing. It works like this:

```
FPInnovation$Wood.fail[LOGICAL TEST] <- updatedvalue
```

So specifically for Speci.no=="DBW-07"

```
FPInnovation$Wood.fail[FPInnovation$Speci.no=="DWB-07"] <- updatedvalue
```

This will select and update the rows satisfying the logical test.

Answer (score 0):

```
row = .... #specify the row number

FPInnovation$Wood.fail[row] <- 90
```